# Does Tensorflow uses vectorization in its operators

Tags: tensorflow

I'm kinda new to tensorflow and just wanted to know if it already performs vectorization in its operators like multiplying matrices and so on.
And if not if its doable.

As an example let's say we have 2 matrices and we want to multiply them. Instead of for loops to do the operation I'm looking for a vectorized way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by vectorization? Give an example. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Added a simple example, hope it helps understand the question.

Comment: Adding an answer.

Comment: Still not clear what this is asking -- about a user API? internal implementation? what is the problem?

Comment: Sean, I've added an example and @HimanshuRai perfectly answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, tensorflow works with tensors, which are like vectors but more generic, so dont worry about loops. Just make sure the matrices you are multiplying have compatible dimension. Its completely tensor arithmetic, which for your case will be vector algebra.